# Oracle - End Child nodes from Hierarchy table

Tags: oracle, hive, impala

I am trying to find the lowest level child nodes from hierarchy table having parent_node_id and child_node_id as below. 
It is returning the mid level child nodes as well. Please help to modify this query and achieve the desired result.

Please suggest to convert same query to Impala, When I am running this query in HUE it is showing error - tableR reference not found.

```
WITH tableR (parent_node_id, child_node_id)
             AS (SELECT e.parent_node_id, e.child_node_id
                   FROM hierarchy e
                  WHERE     parent_node_id IN (select parent_node_id from hierarchy)
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT e.parent_node_id, e.child_node_id
                   FROM hierarchy e 
                        INNER JOIN tableR d
                           ON e.parent_node_id = d.child_node_id
                  )
        SELECT parent_node_id, child_node_id
          FROM tableR
```

Source Table:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
    |child_node_id|parent_node_id| child_desc  |
    +-------------+--------------+-------------+
    |     C1      |      P1      |     Private |
    +-------------+--------------+-------------+
    |     C2      |      P2      |     Public  |     
    +-------------+--------------+-------------+
    |     C11     |      C1      |     Party   |
    +-------------+--------------+-------------+
    |     C12     |      C11     |     Equity  |
    +-------------+--------------+-------------+
    |     123     |      C12     |   Placement |
    +-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|parent_node  |lowest_l_child| child_desc  |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|     P1      |      123     |  Placement  |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|      P2     |       C2    |    Public    |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|     C1      |      123     |  Placement  |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|     C11     |      123     |   Placement |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|     C12     |    123       |   Placement |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard `connect by` query with filtered leaves gives expected output:

```
select connect_by_root(parent_node_id) root_parent, child_node_id, child_desc
  from hierarchy h
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  start with parent_node_id in (select parent_node_id from hierarchy)
  connect by prior child_node_id = parent_node_id
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0cfb2607f635fffe995291233588580e)</sup>**

Unfortunately I don't know solution for Impala :(

Comment: As I said I don't know this platform. Please read this article: [Recursive Subquery Factoring : Hierarchical Queries Using Recursive WITH Clauses](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2). Maybe some of methods described there are available in Impala.

Comment: This query is returning P1 as parent for all the child.
like p1 -123, p1-123, p1-123, p1-123 instead of the above results.

Comment: It is throwing "Connect By Loop" error while running query on actual dataset.